# IIS web.config include generic set of rewrite rules

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have the following situation:

- Multiple web sites running on IIS 10.0
- Web sites running on the same account of a shared hosting service, so no access to machine.config or other configuration files outside the hosting environment
- Each of the web sites share a common set of rewrite rules, but also define their own site specific rewrite rules

Now I want to move the common rewrite rule set to an external file, so it is easier to maintain. Then I want to include these common rule set into the web.config of each site.

I have looked into the following several options, but found out that none of them worked:

- Add a `configSource` attribute to the `<rewrite>` tag. This does not work, as the `<rewrite>` does not allow the `configSection` attribute
- Add a `configSource` attribute to the `<rules>` tag. This does not allow me to extend the rules for a specific site, as it only reads the configuration from the file that is mentioned in the `configSource` attribute
- Add a `file` attribute to the `<rules>` tag. This did not process the rules in the external file. Maybe the format of my external is incorrect then (see below for how this last option is configured).

When using the `file` attribute my web.config was looking like this (only the relevant parts are shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <rewrite>
            <rules file="rules.config" />
            <!-- here I want to add some additional rules, but they were not there during my initial tests -->
        </rewrite>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My rules.config was like this (only relevant parts shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule ...>
       ...
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want? As mentioned above, I do not have access to the IIS configuration files outside of my hosting environment, so I cannot place common rules in the machine.config or the ApplicationHost.config files.

Comment: I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, As far as I know, virtual directories in iis can interact with external files, you can make a virtual directory inside your website and give path of folder that is outside your website folder that has file. Now this folder will act as it is part of your website and you will be able to give virtual path, suppose you have website folder Yoursites\Testsite and you want to access files within Images\first\file\a.pdf, make a virtual directory in side TestWebsite pointing to images \files and access files within it through virual directory.

Comment: Virtual directories are indeed used to share files between multiple sites (or other things). However, the configuration file cannot read files from any virtual directory. I want to share rewrite rules (not files) between multiple sites and somehow "import" them into the web.config of a specific site, but then also want to add site specific rules to the site's web.config

Comment: As far as I know, this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @samwu That is a pity, as I think that would be a powerful feature